# windows phone 8 logging framework - Nlog?

Tags: c#, logging, windows-phone-8

I would like to know if anyone can guide me on the best approach to log into a file in windows phone 8? Or how should the logs be done?  I have already seen NLOG but I have doubts about the LogReceiverService. Where does the WCF is created?

Thanks.

Comment: If you want to log locally, do you need WCF at all? Or are you trying to log to a server?

Comment: I don't need a WCF, but in NLOG they say: "Note that File target and several others are not included because of current constraints of the platform APIs." ... so, what's the best approach so that testers can submit a log file when they find a bug?

Comment: I guess it depends if you want to split the steps of creating the log and sending it. If you wrote your own Target (https://github.com/nlog/nlog/wiki/How-to-write-a-Target) then you could write files to the appropriate place in the phone (or perhaps use the Database target with SQLite db?) and then provide a separate screen to send the log files later?